# jQuery Drag and Drop only drop once in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I made a fiddle for this

http://jsfiddle.net/likwidt/EarWR/3/

Essentially, this works almost the way I want it in IE but Chrome and FF not so much.

I want to drag an item into a drop zone and then have the option to either drag it to another droppable or drag out to revert to it's original position.

When I drop an Item into a dropzone, I can't drag it anymore.

**QUESTION:** WHY CAN'T THE DRAGGABLE BE DRAGGED AGAIN AFTER DROP?  Use the fiddle reset the drag and drop setting to nothing and it still doesn't work I can't explain it...yet I've programmed draggable that can be dragged out of multiple drop zones, what's stopping these ones...also there's an OUT event...WHY if this was the way it was supposed to function.

Has anyone solved this problem before, maybe someone can give me a hint to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You might want to look into `.sortable()` instead of drag and drop. See the [jQuery UI Sortable Demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists) for an example

Comment: The sortable resets the original position so that cute revert function won't work anymore.

Comment: Besides which this works in IE, so from a purely intellectual standpoint, what's the diff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The droppable div is "covering" the droped DIV

If you set the "z-index :999" for example fixed the problem for me.

I would fix the code for you.. but its a mess and my eyes hurt.. So just a simple answer for you in this case

```
.Top{
 z-index : 999;
}
```

add that class to your items.

Comment: You think your eyes hurt, try working on this markup for a few days straight, thanks.

Comment: As for the code being a mess...I'm in the middle of it ok...gimme a break!

Comment: :-) OKay okay.. I can see your stress levels are exploding.. take a break .. have a kit kat ;-) good luck